# Random freezing on multiple systems

Tags: freeze, crash

I have been trying to make ubuntu my daily driver and remove my windows partition, however one thing which is stopping that is that I get random freezes where I have to use the power button to get the system to reboot. Also, worth noting is the fact that I see this behavior on two completely different systems, one a desktop-PC with Nvidia graphics (freezes both with the latest stable nvidia proprietary drivers as well as the beta drivers from graphics ppa) another is a laptop with an AMD APU so I can't pin point the issue.

I would like your help on checking the logs to see what is making the system crash (maybe an application that I use on both the systems?) I tried journalctl -b -1 but all I could find was that pulseaudio was lagging and everything (presumably because of the freeze).

One more thing worth mentioning is that I have SSD+HDD setups on both and I keep my root partition on the SSD and the /home partition on the HDD. Also both the systems run dual boot with windows on one partition.

Edit: My desktop PC has an Intel i5-8600 (non-K) processor and the laptop has a Ryzen 5 2500U processor

Here are the requested outputs:

```
nitish@nitish-PC ~ % free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.3Gi        12Gi       159Mi       1.2Gi        13Gi
Swap:          19Gi          0B        19Gi
nitish@nitish-PC ~ % sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
nitish@nitish-PC ~ % ls -al /var/crash
total 216020
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie      4096 Oct  7 03:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root          4096 Jul 31 22:04 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie         0 Oct  7 03:31 kdump_lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie       322 Oct  7 03:31 kexec_cmd
-rw-r-----  1 nitish   whoopsie 112304145 Oct  5 16:00 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 nitish   whoopsie         0 Oct  5 16:00 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        37 Oct  5 16:00 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 nitish   whoopsie   7171894 Oct  2 14:45 _usr_bin_kdeinit5.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 nitish   whoopsie    684855 Oct  5 16:00 _usr_bin_kglobalaccel5.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 nitish   whoopsie         0 Oct  5 16:00 _usr_bin_kglobalaccel5.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        37 Oct  5 16:00 _usr_bin_kglobalaccel5.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 nitish   whoopsie  15494204 Oct  5 15:14 _usr_bin_kwin_x11.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 nitish   whoopsie  84166950 Oct  6 14:04 _usr_bin_PeaZip_res_7z_7z.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   1195074 Oct  2 14:34 _usr_lib_udisks2_udisksd.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie    151151 Oct  2 13:08 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_libexec_ksysguard_ksgrd_network_helper.0.crash
```

I am not currently running any linux system on my laptop as I gave up long ago and I really wanted it to be stable as I use it for work.

Comment: What processors? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al /var/crash` for both computers.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes deactivate C-State control in motherboard settings can solve the problem, I have an AMD Ryzen 3 with an Asus MB and had the same trouble.